# Using CheckMark in swift

Tags: swift

How to use the method in UITableViewCellAcessoryCheckMark swift? In ObjC it is clear to me, but Swift could not do likewise. My intention is to make a comparison, and this being true chekmark appear.

Comment: How are you trying to make the comparison?

Comment: Thank you! Could also help me in this matter?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489466/relate-the-section-with-the-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift, to reference UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckMark use

`cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark`

Here's the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/UITableViewCellAccessoryType

In Swift 4/5,

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 3 working answer:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

let foods = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "spinach", "grape"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

{
    return foods.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = foods[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```